# Jenkins pipeline fails with error : "docker : permission deinied"

Tags: macos, docker, jenkins, terminal, cicd

I'm trying to run my react & nodeJs project on jenkins with docker, to create CI/CD ability. at the moment I just want to make sure it works in the most simple way.

- I had an error on the same location at the pipeline with message : "docker:not found"
  I've solved it using "-v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker" when starting jenkins.

`Now - I understand I need permission for jenkins to use docker, and I found this terminal command line that should solve it: "usermod -G docker -a jenkins" and I get an error (on a Mac) : "zsh: command not found: usermod"`

any help would be appreciated, to modify or replace this line, or another idea that might work. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Mac does not come with the `passwd` package that contains `usermod`. An alternative to managing user groups is described here. [usermod equivalent in OSX](https://superuser.com/questions/60150/is-there-a-usermod-equivalent-in-terminal-for-os-x-10-6-1)